# Shiny app with editable datatable: How can I enable the modification of the table when I use selectInput option?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this little shiny app (made with much appreciated help, I'm new to shiny...). I need to be able to modify numbers in the table so that the graph will update with the new numbers.

In my app, this all work fine for the first species (sentosa) that show up. However, if I swith the species to versicolor, I can't change the numbers in the table anymore and of course the graph doesn't update.

It seem to me that the row-col identification of the editing in the table dosen't follow up when I use `selectInput`. Is there a way that I can edit the datatable for all the species and keep the `selectInput` option?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

ui<-navbarPage("Planifier les cultures",
               theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
           tabPanel(
               "Cultures",
               sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                inputPanel(
                                    selectInput("Species", label = "Choisir l'espèces",
                                                choices = levels(as.factor(iris$Species)))
                                )),
                   mainPanel(DTOutput("iris_datatable"),
                             hr(),
                             plotOutput("iris_plot"))
               )
           ),
           tabPanel("Fertilisation"),
           tabPanel("Analyse de sol")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    my_iris <- reactiveVal(iris)
    output$iris_datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(my_iris() %>% filter(Species==input$Species),
                      options = list(pageLength = 10),
                      editable= TRUE,
                      rownames= FALSE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$iris_datatable_cell_edit,{
        edit <- input$iris_datatable_cell_edit # just to simplify typing, can keep long form for later
        print(edit) # debugging, remove in prod
        temp_myiris <- my_iris() # hold the current my_iris in a temp dataframe
        temp_myiris[edit$row, edit$col+1] <- edit$value # set the value in the correct spot
        my_iris(temp_myiris)        # set the temp_myiris as the new my_iris
    })
    output$iris_plot <- renderPlot({
        my_iris() %>%
            filter(Species==input$Species) %>% 
            select(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length) %>% 
            mutate(Sepal.Length=as.numeric(Sepal.Length),
                   Petal.Length=as.numeric(Petal.Length)) %>%
            pivot_longer(cols=Sepal.Length:Petal.Length, names_to = "type", values_to = "valeur") %>%
            group_by(type) %>%
            summarize(somme=sum(valeur, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
            ungroup() %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = type, y = as.numeric(somme))) + # I'm casting to numeric here because edit$value returns as a character, so need to coerce to number otherwise plots funny.
            geom_point(size=3)
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.  You are displaying a subset (50 records) of the original dataset with 150 records.  However, you are trying the change the values in the original dataset.  That will not work if you choose anything other than the first selection for Species.  Also, when you change your selection, the previous changes are lost.  To retain the changes, you need to make the changes in the original dataset also.  Next, to ensure that the edited changes are reflected in the sub dataset, you need to subset it outside of `output$iris_datatable`.  Try the code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

ui<-navbarPage("Planifier les cultures",
               theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
               tabPanel(
                 "Cultures",
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                inputPanel(
                                  selectInput("Species", label = "Choisir l'espèces",
                                              choices = levels(as.factor(iris$Species)))
                                )),
                   mainPanel(DTOutput("iris_datatable"),
                             hr(),
                             plotOutput("iris_plot"))
                 )
               ),
               tabPanel("Fertilisation"),
               tabPanel("Analyse de sol")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_iris <- reactiveValues(df=iris,sub=NULL, sub1=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$Species, {
    my_iris$sub <- my_iris$df %>% filter(Species==input$Species)
    my_iris$sub1 <- my_iris$df %>% filter(Species!=input$Species)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$iris_datatable <- renderDT({
    n <- length(names(my_iris$sub))
    DT::datatable(my_iris$sub,
                  options = list(pageLength = 10),
                  selection='none', editable= list(target = 'cell'), 
                  rownames= FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$iris_datatable_cell_edit,{
    edit <- input$iris_datatable_cell_edit # just to simplify typing, can keep long form for later
    print(edit) # debugging, remove in prod
    str(edit)
    i <- edit$row
    j <- edit$col + 1
    v <- edit$value
    
    my_iris$sub[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, my_iris$sub[i, j])  ## editing changes in the displayed dataset
    
    my_iris$df <<- rbind(my_iris$sub1,my_iris$sub)  ## reflecting changes in the original dataset
  })
  
  output$iris_plot <- renderPlot({
    my_iris$sub %>%
      select(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length) %>% 
      mutate(Sepal.Length=as.numeric(Sepal.Length),
             Petal.Length=as.numeric(Petal.Length)) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols=Sepal.Length:Petal.Length, names_to = "type", values_to = "valeur") %>%
      group_by(type) %>%
      summarize(somme=sum(valeur, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
      ungroup() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = type, y = as.numeric(somme))) + # I'm casting to numeric here because edit$value returns as a character, so need to coerce to number otherwise plots funny.
      geom_point(size=3)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @YBS is `my_iris$sub[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, my_iris$sub[i, j])`  happening in the global enviroment, or inside shiny server?

Comment: Inside shiny server.  See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html) for more info.

Comment: Hey @YBS. What I am trying to do is almost the same. Bu the issue comes when I go to the third page and edit some values, it always rerenders and jumps back to the first page(even though the edits are saved). How can I solve this?